# Cursors in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cursor

Thanks for looking and helping!

I've written this very simple cursor, but for some reason it does't want to work:

```
drop table if exists t1;
drop procedure if exists simple_loop;
create temporary table values ('chris'),('peter'),('brian'),('stewie'),('meg');
create procedure simple_loop()
begin
declare finished int default false;
declare n varchar(45);
declare c cursor for select name from t1;
declare continue handler for not found set finished = true;
open c;
c_loop: loop
    fetch c into n;
    --if finished then leave c_loop;
    select n;
end loop;
end
```

As you can see, I have commented out the line that says to leave the loop when the results are done. This is because the whole procedure script won't execute.

If the line is there, it will not complain about that line causing an issue, but the end:

> ...the right syntac to use near 'loop;end' ErrorCode: 1064

I do not know why that is. The MySQL documentation does't seem to be much help. If I also add the line 'close c;' it won't work either, but pointing out the whole end as an error.

Any pointers much appreciated.

MySQL version is 5.5 on Ubuntu.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Works for me: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b0f6/1).

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be fixed! I forgot to terminate that if statement:

```
drop table if exists t1;
drop procedure if exists simple_loop;
create temporary table values ('chris'),('peter'),('brian'),('stewie'),('meg');
create procedure simple_loop()begin
declare finished int default false;
declare n varchar(45);
declare c cursor for select name from t1;
declare continue handler for not found set finished = true;
open c;
c_loop: loop
    fetch c into n;
    if finished then leave c_loop; end if;
    select n;
end loop;
end
```

look at the previously commented out line:

```
if finished then leave c_loop; END IF;
```